# OpenGL/PBO pixel drawing example needed

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, pixel, pbo

I need to draw pixels very fast on a screen.

I found this interesting page
[Fast pixel drawing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288221/fast-pixel-drawing-library)

author posted:
"Using an OpenGL texture along with a PBO seems to be the best choice. Thanks."

I guess OpenGL/PBO is what i need.

I was reading about PBO
here http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/pixel_buffer_object.txt
and here http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html
but i don't get it...

Can someone provide simple example, how to draw pixels on a bitmap on a 2D texture with PBO extension?

Comment: Using a PBO seems like an unnecessary step.  Why not render a 2D texture directly?

Comment: @luke PBO typically DMA to the graphics card they are good if you are doing video.

Comment: @Martin interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a good place to start [OpenGL Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html)

If you need to draw an image then the easiest way is textures, basically a 2D block of memory that you write pixel RGB (or whatever) values into an then ask openGL to draw to the screen. VBOs and PBOs just improve on the process of getting the texture to the screen.

To draw individual 3D points then you need to learn more about OpenGL [start here](http://www.opengl.org/code/)

Comment: example from this page is a little bit sophisticated, for someone who doesn't know OpenGL. Can you provide simple example, please? (one PBO, one texture, and a function draw_pixel_now(x,y,R,G,B) )